# PHP Change sql ouput to be a hyperlink

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink

I'm a total beginner when it comes to SQL and PHP coding. I have a page that does a select from a SQL db.

```
<?php
    while( $row=$DATA->table()->next() )
    {
        echo "<tr>
              <td>{$row->columns("ProName")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("A")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Astart")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Aslut")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("B")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Bstart")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Bslut")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("C")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Cstart")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Cslut")->value()}</td>
              <td>{$row->columns("Link")->value()}'</td>
          </tr>";
      }
?>
```

That is working fantastic, but I need the last line to be a click-able hyperlink (the line with this information: `<td>{$row->columns("Link")->value()}'</td>`

I tried a little bit of everything, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 <td>{$row->columns("Link")->value()}'</td>
```

to

```
<a href='{$row->columns("Link")->value()}'>Link</a>
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a lot. Working just like it should.